# How to use emojis on the subject line of mail?

Tags: shell-script, email, postfix, mail-command

I am writing a shell script to setup a few servers and once it is done, it will send an email to our help desk letting us know that the server is ready to be used.

**I would like to use the following subject line:** `New Space Loop Activated!`

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make accept that emoji. I can use emojis on the email body, but it does not work on the subject.

```
#
# Send an email to let us know that the server is ready to be used.
# Credentials will be sent to Vault instead of being stored on the server
# once the Vault server has been properly configured.
#
# @since 0.0.1
#
mail -s 'New Space Loop Activated!' \
-a 'From:Kerb!am Man<kerblam@domain.tld>' help@domain.tld << END_MAIL
Delivery for The Humans,

Your new space loop ($HOSTNAME) has been configured $(printf '\xf0\x9f\x8e\x89') and credentials are
available at /home/gatekeeper/. Please remove them from the server once they
have been placed in a secure location.

Delivery fulfilled,
Kerb!am Man $(printf '\xf0\x9f\xa4\x96\n')

And remember: if you want it, Kerblam it!
END_MAIL
```

I have tried a few ideas:

- Tried using [encoded-character](https://mailutils.org/manual/html_node/encoded_002dcharacter.html), but it does not seem to work for shell scripts — or I am too stupid to figure it out
- Tried using unicode and utf-8
- Tried using `printf` and `echo`

But nothing seems to work. Is that even supported? I am using `postfix` and `mailutils`, with [Postmark](https://postmarkapp.com) as the SMTP relay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character  in UTF-8 is:

```
f0 9f 8e 89
```

So you need this string in the subject line:

```
=?utf-8?Q?=F0=9F=8E=89?=
```

or for the whole subject:

```
New Space Loop Activated! =?utf-8?Q?=F0=9F=8E=89?=
```

The sequence means character set is `utf-8` and the `Q` means quoted-printable encoding. You can also use BASE64 encoding to save a few bytes.

Comment: Great, that worked! Do you know where I can find documentation for this? I would like to read more on it.

Comment: See https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt

Comment: works in ubuntu 18.04 LTS :D
not working in Red Hat 4.8.5-36 :(.  subject reads: "New Space Loop Activated! ␦" when arriving in my inbox.  I'll try checking and updating posfix and mailutils